# Suntour derailleur compatibility with shimano shifter

Tags: shimano, gears, derailleur-rear, shifter, compatibility

I bought today a bike with a Suntour rear derailleur (XR 150 8 speed) for my daughter. It has old rotating shifters I with to replace with triggers.
Will a shimano 8 speed (e.g. Altus/Acera) fit this derailleur ?

I am not sure of the cassette brand, but the rear wheel hub is a Deore LX.

Comment: Generally all 7/8/9 have the same cable pull and are therefore compatible even between brands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to come down to the **cable pull ratio**: that is, how far the derailleur moves sideways for a given cable pull from the shifter.

Suntour hasn't made derailleurs for decades, so it will be hard to find experiences using them documented online. Based on [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/rec.bicycles.tech/c/sacEQh2iQDg), I would not be optimistic. The cassette (or possibly freewheel in this case) will only complicate matters further, since the distance between sprockets will also determine how well your setup shifts.

> All derailleurs do not behave exactly
> the same way. Why should they? Suntour requires a different amount of
> cable pull compared to Shimano to move the same amount of lateral distance
> across the cogset. Specifically, Shimano derailleurs require about 10% more
> cable travel to achieve the same amount of movement across the cogset than
> Accushift. So the mixed marriage of Suntour and Shimano may sort-of work
> over 5 cogs or so, but eventually the cumulative error at the ends of the
> cogset will cause sloppy shifting.

Answer (score 1):

Last week I put this derailleur on a bike I want to set at minimum cost. I put on it an old indexed 7-speed shifter (shimano), and it works quite well. It is rather noisy, but it does not come from the cable pull : I manage to get the full range of a 7 speed freehub.